# Keep user logged in swift

Tags: json, swift

My requirement is to do login the user and keep logged until he logs out. for example, If the user logged in and closes the app, next time when he opens it he should get redirected to HOMEPAGE otherwise to LOGIN PAGE.

something like this

```
if current user ! = nil { performsegue(withIdentifier: "LOGINPAGESEGUE", sender: nil) } else { performsegue(withIdentifier: "HOMEPAGESEGUE", sender: nil)}
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: You need to provide more info. How are you authenticating?

Comment: based on token. I got token when user logs in. I am storing that token in userDefaults.

Comment: If you store the token, then just check if the token is still valid when the application starts. What part do you need help with specifically?

Comment: if I want to redirect the user based on logic, where should I write the code? in loginpageVC or launchstoryboardVC?

Comment: It's up to you. A popular way of doing this is having a "boot viewcontroller / view" that does checks. Perhaps it shows the logo of your app on startup with a spinner... and then does some loading. While doing this, it is also checking the token.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Bool` `UserDefaults` like `isLoggedIn` and then set `true` when the user Login the and set `false` when the user clicks Logout.

The main thing you have to do is you have to check the `isLoggedIn` every time when the user opens the app like on `AppDelegate` or in `firstViewController` of your app.

How to check:
if `isLoggedIn` is `true` then redirect to the main screen or else navigate to the login.

You can use my file to work easily with `UserDefaults`
https://gist.github.com/HarshadPipaliya/b9c58dbc555679544eb76601f16f2036

```
var isLoggedIn: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    }
}
```

Use this to set data in userDafaults `UserDefaultsData.shared.isLoggedIn = true`

Use this to get data from userDafaults `let loggedIn: Bool = UserDefaultsData.shared.isLoggedIn`

Comment: could you please show me how to write this code in AppDelegate in loginVc page?

Comment: For the easiest way just put one splash screen before login and check in ViewDidLoad of splash.swift for isLoggedIn and navigate programmatically to the appropriate screens

Comment: if i create a viewcontroller for launchscreen storyboard, it is throwing errors

Comment: you have to create new UIViewController inside main.storyboard, not inside of launch screen storyboard.

Comment: same as you created the login screen.

Comment: I got it. I have created UINavigationController class then wrote condition for token. Thank you

Comment: Great, enjoy Coding :)

Comment: If the issue is resolved then please maintain Solved flag. Thanks